# Jquery hover but not on active

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7, hover

I have a piece of code that I've written to get my vertical navigation to have a small fade in/out hover effect on the image. The only problem is I can't get the active to NOT do anything.

All I want is the image to fade in/out on my navigation but stay at 100% opacity when active and not animate on hover. The problem with the code below is they all animate even if not active?

Now I'm no jquery expert but it's something I want to learn so any help would be appreciated.

```
      if (!$(".view-sidebar-links .views-row a").hasClass("active")) {
                $(".view-sidebar-links .views-row").hover(
                    function() {
                    $("img", this).fadeTo("fast", 1);;
                },
                function() {
                    $("img", this).fadeTo("fast", 0.33);;
    });
  };
```

The html

```
     <div class="view-content">

       <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
        <h2 class="title"><a href="/alpiniainstitute/about/clinical-devlopment">Clinical devlopment</a></h2>    
        <a href="/alpiniainstitute/about/clinical-devlopment"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/alpiniainstitute/sites/default/files/styles/sidebar_links/public/images/slideshow/image01.jpg" /></a>
      </div>

      <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
       <h2 class="title"><a href="/alpiniainstitute/about/technological-development">Technological development</a></h2>    
       <a href="/alpiniainstitute/about/technological-development"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/alpiniainstitute/sites/default/files/styles/sidebar_links/public/images/header-images/Screen%20shot%202012-05-11%20at%2010.05.30.png" /></a>
      </div>

      <div class="views-row views-row-3 views-row-odd views-row-last">
       <h2 class="title"><a href="/alpiniainstitute/team" class="active">Our Team</a></h2>    
       <a href="/alpiniainstitute/team" class="active"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/alpiniainstitute/sites/default/files/styles/sidebar_links/public/images/header-images/team-header-image.jpg" /></a>    
      </div>

    </div>
```

Edit:

I'm so close.

```
    $(".views-row").delegate("a:not(.active)", "mouseenter", function() {
      $('img').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    }).delegate("a:not(.active)", "mouseleave", function() {
      $('img').fadeTo('fast', 0.33);
    });
```

I've managed to get it working, now as you can see the code above works on all images on the page. If I add ('img', this) it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is a tad incorrect. You're setting an event handler in a conditional, not the other way around (i.e. checking a conditional in an event handler).

Also, try a delegate:

```
$('.views-row')
    .on('mouseover', 'a:not(.active)', function () {
        $('img', this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
    })
    .on('mouseout', 'a:not(.active)', function () {
        $('img', this).fadeTo('fast', 0.33);
    });
```

This way, if your view rows toggle their `active` class on/off, you'll still be able to check on the fly whether to run the handlers or not, while also minimizing the number of event handlers you actually put out their on your DOM.

Comment: Thanks but I get an error message, missing ) after argument list. I put the ) in and then it says .on is not a function.

Comment: `.on()` is available for jQuery 1.7+ only (which I'd suggest you use anyway). If you're stuck with a lower version, check out `delegate()`, which is basically it's older equivalent.

Comment: Ok I'll give a go. I'm using Drupal 7 to build my site and even with the jquery update module only takes it to jquery 1.5.2. So i'll try delegate and see if I can come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the .not('selector') in Jquery

Updated: Try this:

```
$(".views-row").delegate("a:not(.active)", "mouseenter", function() {
  $(this).find('img').fadeTo('fast', 1);
}).delegate("a:not(.active)", "mouseleave", function() {
  $(this).find('img').fadeTo('fast', 0.33);
});
```

Comment: This makes the links hover and the images change but the active still animates. When I narrow it down further in $(".views-sidebar-links .views-row a").not then it doesn't work. Am I right in saying the code above doesn't work on the the active class because the .not('.active') is on .views-row?